# How can I run 2 processes at the same time?

Tags: python

I'm making an alarm clock in python and I need to start 2 processes. The first one should display a window, and the second one should start the sound. process1 and process2, despite multiprocessing, run alternately, not simultaneously. Here is the code:

```
#import for time
from datetime import datetime
#import for interface
from tkinter import *
#import for parallel use
from multiprocessing import *
#import functions
from alarm_interface import window
from alarm_sound import alarm_sound

#Function that checks valid time

def valid_alarm(val_al):
    if int(str(val_al[0:2]))>23 or int(str(val_al[3:5]))>59:
        return "Invalid time"
    else:
        return "Pass"

#Main programm that asks user for title and time for alarm

while True:
    print('Title of the alarm clock:',end=' ')
    name_of_alarm=input('')

    print('Select the desired time. Enter the hour and minute')

    print('Hour:',end='')
    user_time_hour=int(input()[0:2])

    print('Minute:',end='')
    user_time_min=int(input()[0:2])

    user_time="{:02d}:{:02d}".format(user_time_hour,user_time_min)

    #Checking valid time
    if valid_alarm(user_time)=="Invalid time":
        print(valid_alarm(user_time))
    else:
        print(("The alarm clock is set to {:02d}:{:02d}").format(user_time_hour,user_time_min))
        break

#Main programm that compares current time and user time
while True:

    current_time=str(datetime.now().time())[:5]

    if current_time==user_time:
        print(name_of_alarm)
        #multiprocessing
        process1=Process(target=alarm_sound())
        process2=Process(target=window())

        process2.start()
        process1.start()
        process2.join()
        process1.join()
```

I tried to start these 2 processes with thread library and multiprocessing library

Comment: try using multi-threading, here is an example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the code:

1. Missing [Safe importing of main module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods)

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python
> interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a
> new process).
>
> For example, using the spawn or forkserver start method running the
> following module would fail with a RuntimeError:
>
> from multiprocessing import Process
>
> ```
> def foo():
>     print('hello')
>
> p = Process(target=foo)
> p.start()
> ```
>
> Instead one should protect the “entry point” of the program by using
> `if __name__ == '__main__'`: as follows:
>
> from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support, set_start_method
>
> ```
> def foo():
>     print('hello')
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     freeze_support()
>     set_start_method('spawn')
>     p = Process(target=foo)
>     p.start()
> ```

2. You are invoking the functions on `Process` initialization

   ```
   Process(target=alarm_sound())
   ```

   should be

   ```
   Process(target=alarm_sound)
   ```

Code sample:

```
def get_user_time():
    while True:
        print('Title of the alarm clock:', end=' ')
        name_of_alarm = input('')
        ...
        if valid_alarm(user_time) == "Invalid time":
            print(valid_alarm(user_time))
        else:
            print(("The alarm clock is set to {:02d}:{:02d}").format(user_time_hour, user_time_min))
            return user_time, name_of_alarm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_time, name_of_alarm = get_user_time()
    while True:
        current_time = str(datetime.now().time())[:5]
        if current_time == user_time:
            print(name_of_alarm)
            process1 = Process(target=alarm_sound)
            process2 = Process(target=window)
            process2.start()
            process1.start()
            process2.join()
            process1.join()
```